# TypeScript: array type to tuple type assertion

Tags: typescript

I researched the question but didn't found an answer. So, the question is:

> Why TypeScript allows to assert number[] type to [string, number] tuple type?

Code listing:

```js
const arr: number[] = [1, 2];
const arr2: [string, number] = arr as [string, number];
alert(arr2[0].split(''));
```

The main peace of the code is:

> arr as [string, number]

With types it looks like:

> number[] as [string, number]

Comment: You try tu use `.split()` on a number. arr2[0] = 1, You cannot do `1.split()`

Comment: I understand it, but problem is in that TypeScript allows to compile the code

Comment: Assertions intentionally allow unsound changes; however it usually enforces that you either widen or narrow the type, and if you want to assert to an "unrelated" type it needs to go through `any` or `unknown` as in `arr as any as [string, number]`.  In this case it seems to be allowing the length to be narrowed to `2` from `number` while also allowing the index signature property to be widened from `number` to `string | number`.  Each of those would be fine separately; I am surprised it allows both at once, though.  Could be a bug/design limitation in TS.  Still researching.

Comment: @jcalz, it will be very strange if the compiler really wide number to union type string | number, but it can happen if it at first collect all types in the tuple, build union type based on them, then compare [number, number, ...] with [string | number, string | number] and after fixed tuple type I asked. But here is one strange moment, if it works like that, why compiler normally throws an error in the case `const arr: [number, number] = [1, 2]`?

Comment: You can imagine `number[] as (string | number)[] as [string, number]`, where the first is a widening and the second is a narrowing. What do you mean there's an error in `const arr: [number, number] = [1, 2]`  [I don't see that anywhere](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwQLhgbTAVwLYCMCmCANDFnoQLowC86AjCQEwUDcMA9O6SDIQiAgCEMIA).

Comment: @jcalz, I mean an alternate example
`const arr: [number, number] = [1, 2]; const arr2: [string, number] = arr as [string, number];`

Comment: @jcalz, I understood what did you think, may be you are right